# Invoking signalR Hub method when a javascript function is called in client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, signalr

I have written the following code to establish connection with signalR server and invoke a hub method:

```
<script>
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/signalRServer").withAutomaticReconnect().build();
             connection.start().then( result => {
               console.log("RealTime connection is now established")
             });
            function ShowMessageAndUpdate(messageId, data){
                $('#messageModal').modal('show');
                $('#mainTxt').text(data);
    
                var formData2 = new FormData();
                formData2.append("messageId", messageId);
                        
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Messages/UpdateMessageStatus",
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: formData2,
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response.success) {
                            console.log("status changed successfully!");
                            var table2 = $('#table2').DataTable();
                            table2.ajax.reload();
                            connection.invoke("MessageUpdate", messageId).catch(function(err){
                            return console.error(err)
                        });
                        } else {
                            console.log("status change failed.");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });
            }
</script>
```

The hub method is invoked when the success response of jQuery is `True`.
The problem is that console cannot establish a connection with the hub.

> Messages:377 Error: Failed to invoke 'MessageUpdate' due to an error
> on the server.
> at H. (signalr.js:1:13973)
> at L.I (signalr.js:1:14804)
> at X.L.connection.onreceive (signalr.js:1:10649)
> at WebSocket.r.onmessage (signalr.js:1:27565)

Is there anything wrong with my client side code?

Update:
method in the hub is as follows:

```
public async Task MessageUpdate(int messageId)
    {
        int destination = _messageRepository.GetSenderIdByMessageId(messageId);
        string username = _userRepository.GetUserNameById(destination);
        var userId = NtoIdMappingTable.GetValueOrDefault(username);
        await Clients.User(userId.FirstOrDefault()).SendAsync("ReceiveMessageUpdate");
    }
```

The problem is in client side, because method is not run when debugging. connection cannot be established correctly when it gets parameter from `function(parameter)`.